# What is the maximum value that $P[D]$ can take?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three events with $P[A] = 0.7$, $P[B] = 0.7$ and $P[C] = 0.7$. Let $D$ be the event "exactly one of the three events $A$, $B$, $C$ occurs". What is the maximum value that $P[D]$ can take?

**My attempt**

$D=(A\cap B^C\cap C^C)\cup (A^C\cap B^C\cap C^C)\cup (A^C\cap B^C\cap C)$.

[Boole's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality) is sharp iff $P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$ , so we have:$$P(D)=P((A\cap B^C\cap C^C))+P((A^C\cap B^C\cap C^C))+P((A^C\cap B^C\cap C))$$

I read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216329/finding-the-minimum-and-maximum-value-of-pa-and-b/216330#216330) that $P(A\cap B)$ is maximal iff it's equal to $\min\{P(A),P(B)\}$ since $P(A\cap B)$ is always smaller than $P(A)$ or $P(B)$.

So I get $P(D)=0.3+0.3+0.3=0.9$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often clearer to use what I call a "line" diagram rather than a Venn diagram.

$AAAAAAA---$
$---BBBBBBB$
$-CCCCCCC--$

It should be abundantly clear that $P(D) = 0$, however we juggle the diagram

Comment: You interpret $P(A)=0.7$ laplacian as saying "$A$ will occur in $7$ of $10$ cases", likewise for $B$ and $C$. I really like the diagram, is it your invention?

Comment: Glad you like it. Re the line diagram, you can say that I have "invented" it as I haven't come across it  it in any textbook.